# ¿Se pueden bloquear ciudades con htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Ha diario recibo trafico robot a mi sitio web con la intención de que yo pierda mi cuenta de **Google AdSense**. He sabido manejar muy bien la situación y he bloqueado todos los países de los que provienen el trafico robot utilizando este código en mi archivo .htaccess

```
# Lista de países bloqueados
GeoIPEnable On
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE RS DenyCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US DenyCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE MX DenyCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE AU DenyCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE NL DenyCountry
Allow from all
Deny from env=DenyCountry
```

Lo que si me llama mucho la atención saber, es si se pueden bloquear las ciudades de los países usando este mismo código, solo que cambiando el **Código iso**.

### Otras soluciones

Actualmente yo puede bloquear una ciudad usando código PHP, obteniendo la ubicación del visitante y creando una condición para sacarlo de la pagina o mandarlo para algún lugar en especifico, y eso también estaría bien, pero yo pienso que seria mucho más interesante si yo lo pudiera controlar con htaccess

Por favor si alguien sabe algo a cerca de este tema, que me lo haga saber.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133013/discussion-on-question-by-braylin-ivan-payano-se-pueden-bloquear-ciudades-con-h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo que utilices [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/es-es/). Lo que hace esta herramienta es ponerse entre tus visitantes y tu servidor, y con esto te ahorras que tu servidor tenga que hacer el trabajo "sucio".

Para que funcione, tienes que apuntar los servidores DNS de tu dominio a Cloudflare (te explican cómo hacerlo).

Es una herramienta muy completa, y con la versión gratuita se pueden hacer muchas cosas: puedes usarla para que cachee tu contenido estático y que tu página se cargue más rápido, crear reglas de redirección, protegerte de bots maliciosos, usar un certificado gratuito para que tu página sea segura (https),... y un sinfín de cosas más.

Para lo que buscas, tienen la opción de los [Workers](https://workers.cloudflare.com/). Tienen un artículo que hablan sobre la [geolocalización de las peticiones](https://blog.cloudflare.com/location-based-personalization-using-workers/). Acabo de hacer una prueba rápida y es relativamente fácil de implementar.

Con esto debería valerte para lo que buscas.